# Dotnet-ef tool backwards compatibility?

Tags: .net-core, entity-framework-core

If I update the dotnet-ef tool from 3.1.8 to 5.0.1, will this still work with 3.1 projects? If I use 5.0.1 it would still produce the same schemas as 3.1.8 for 3.1 projects?

Or should I be using the dotnet tool manifest for my 3.1 projects to specify the 3.1 tools?

Comment: Have you checked the documentation? Maybe there is a migration information and how version 5 relates to version 3.x. It would be my first place to check.

Comment: Same question: no clues on [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/ef/core/cli/dotnet)

Answer (score 1):

I [asked to Microsoft](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/23843), below the response:

> Yes, the tool is backwards compatible; it's a thin wrapper. I would
> always update to the latest version. Note, however, that 2.2 is
> out-of-support.